# AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager <Excel Connection Manager> failed with error code 0xC0202009

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb

I have an SSIS package which reads an Excel File (Data Flow Source) and transfer the data to SQL Server using OLEDB Destination Data Flow Item. The OLEDB Connection Manager used for the destination is configured to use Windows Authentication. The package works fine on my development machine. But when I open the same package on another machine and try to execute it gives the following error in Validation phase

> Error: 0xC020801C at DFT_NSOffers, Source - 'Subscription Offers$' 1 [347]: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "ExcelConnection_NSOffers" failed with error code 0xC0202009.
>   Error: 0xC0047017 at DFT_NSOffers, DTS.Pipeline: component "Source - 'Subscription Offers$' 1" (347) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>   Error: 0xC004700C at DFT_NSOffers, DTS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
>   Error: 0xC0024107 at DFT_NSOffers: There were errors during task validation

I'm using SQL Server 2005 (Version - 9.0.1399)

How do I fix this? Do I need to install any other component or service pack?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think it's 64/32 bit error. My Dev machine and DB server are 32bit. But I could make it work. I had to set `Delay Validation` property of `Data Flow` tasks to `TRUE`.

Comment: I was having a very similar problem--I didn't move machines, just the folder location of the Excel file (as an initial test of pulling in Excel Connection Manager's connection string from a configuration file). This solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks. More detail is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramoji/archive/2009/03/10/the-acquireconnection-method-call-to-the-connection-manager-failed-with-error-code-0xc0202009.aspx

Comment: This worked for me but I had to close the solution and delete the .vs folder first. It did not work just changing to Delay Validation property.

Comment: I resolved by executing SSIS as an administrator.

Answer (score 4):

Hi This can be solved by changing the prorperty of the project in the solution explorer then give `false` to `64bit runtime` option

Answer (score 3):

64/32 bit error? I found this as a problem as my dev machine was 32bit and the production server 64bit. If so, you may need to call the 32bit runtime directly from the command line.

This link says it better (No 64bit JET driver): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/da076e51-8149-4948-add1-6192d8966ead/

Comment: My problem was 32/64 bit as well.  Same error message.  I had a 32 bit ODBC source set up, fought with it for hours, added a 64-bit system source, and my ssis package worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to resolve the "Excel connection issue" in my case it was not a 64 bit issue like some of them had encounterd, I noticed the package worked fine when i didnt enable the package configuration, but i wanted my package to run with the configuration file, digging further into it i noticed i had selected all the properties that were available, I unchecked all and checked only the ones that I needed to store in the package configuration file. and ta dha it works :)

Answer (score 3):

For me, I was accessing my `XLS` file from a network share. Moving the file for my connection manager to a local folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are receiving preview of data in the excel source. But while executing the data flow task you receive Acquire connection error. Then move the file to local system and change the file path in excel connection manager and try executing again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of the previous solutions here worked. Apparently Visual Studio, upon creating the Excel Source component, opens the Excel file and does not release it. Trying to then execute the SSIS package within Visual Studio leads to a AcquireConnection error with code 0xC0202009. Closing Visual Studio completely (not just the solution), reopen the solution and then run the package again without any further changes works. I found out when I tried to replace the Excel file and Windows Explorer said it couldn't because the file was open.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the 32/64 bit driver which I solved by configuring the properties of the sql server job:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!  I had read numerous times about changing to 32 bit on the SSIS package itself but this was the first time I saw it mentioned on the SQL Agent Job step - this fixed my issue right away, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue just that excel was the destination in my case instead of source as in the case of the original question/issue. I have spent hours to resolve this issue but looks like finally Soniya Parmar saved the day for me. I have set job and let it run for few iterations already and all is good now. As per her suggestion I set up the delay validation of the Excel connection manager to 'True. Thanks Soniya

Answer (score 0):

Setting RetainSameConnection property to True for Excel manager Worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, trying to load data from Excel spreadsheet; and was running on WinX64. So I went VS BI`s project properties: Configuration Properties \ Dbugging 
and Switch Run64BitRuntime from True to False.
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error and it simply got resolved after installing the MS offices driver and Execute the job in 32 Bit DTEXEC. Now it works fine.

You can get the setup from below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Answer (score 0):

In my case password i set in expression was wrong causing this error. After assigning correct password to expression of connection manager issue resolved.

Answer (score -4):

In order to resolve this issue make all your data flow tasks in one sequence. It means it should not execute parallel. One data flow task sequence should contain only one data flow task and for this another data flow task as sequence.

Ex:-

[image]